# Not able to open setting in windows terminal

Tags: terminal, settings, windows-11

I am using Windows 11.
I want to open settings for windows terminal. But instead it open a json file.
[image]
What is issue here and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is your windows terminal up to date? I know it used to be the case that there wasn't a GUI settings before

Comment: oh thanks! I updated and yes now it is working

Comment: Great! Glad to help out